# Regular expression is giving wrong result

Tags: java, regex

I am writing a simple regular expression program using the expression:

`uid=swg2*([C]?[1247]\d{6})`

Initially I tried to get a valid input string for this expression using the online [regex tool](https://regex101.com/) and got a valid example string as `uid=swg2C1\dddddd`.

I also tried with `uid=swg2C1\\123456` in my Java program but getting same issue.

Now if I use this in my Java program then it is not working as expected:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "uid=swg2C1\\dddddd"; // Tried with "uid=swg2C1\\123456", same issue
    if (Pattern.compile("uid=swg2*([C]?[1247]\\d{6})").matcher(input).find()) {
        System.out.println("valid input");
    } else {
        System.out.println("invalid input");
    }
}
```

If I run this program I am getting message as invalid input. But my string is valid input as per the [online tool](https://regex101.com/). Please help me what is wrong with my input data.

Comment: That's not a valid input string `\\d` is Java RegEx for `\d` - i.e. a digit. So `\\d{6}` is "exactly 6 digits` - not `\dddddd`.

Comment: Use this website to test/learn regular expressions

https://regex101.com/

Comment: @BoristheSpider, I tried this input - `uid=swg2C1\\123456` getting same issue

Comment: @BikramjitRajbongshi, The link in my post already says I am using regex101.com, I tried in that site but the same is not working in my Java program

Comment: The "same" is not working in Java, because you need to escape ``\`` characters in a Java literal, so ``\\`` becomes ``\\\\``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not escape your backslashes!

```
uid=swg2*([C]?[1247]\\d{6})
                    ^^
             These should be escaped!
```

In Java code, if you did not escape them, the two backslashes in Java code will become one `\` in regex. This means that the engine will treat the string like this:

```
uid=swg2*([C]?[1247]\d{6})
```

`\d` means digits, so the engine thinks you are trying to match 6 digits!

So, remember to escape them by adding one more `\` before each `\`:

```
"uid=swg2*([C]?[1247]\\\\d{6})"
```

Comment: I am already escaping it in my java program, I just single `\` not double `\\` , `uid=swg2*([C]?[1247]\\d{6})` is my Java regular expression

Comment: @user3181365 In regex, to match a single \ you need \\. So in Java, to write two backslashes, you need 4 backslashes. Just try running your code with 4 backslashes!

Comment: Sorry, I just need to use single `\` so I escaped with 2 backslashes. I don't want 2 \\. Now I updated my post to avoid confusion

Comment: @user3181365 Ah I see. Then your regex is wrong. And you got it right by chance by escaping the single \ in the online regex tester. You actually don't need to escape the regex like you do in Java code in there. Your regex should have been with 2 backslashes in the first place, because 2 backslashes in regex matches one backslash in a string. Then, in order to use this regex with 2 backslashes in Java code, you need to escape the two backslashes again.

Comment: Thanks Sweeper, But I don't want to change the regular expression in my Java program. Can you please help me what is wrong with my input data?

Comment: @user3181365 `\d` means digits in regex, so you can just give it 6 digits (like 123456) instead of dddddd

Comment: Yes, I have already tried with `uid=swg2C1\\123456` but having same issue.

Comment: @user3181365 You need to remove the backslashes also, because you are not matching any backslashes now so `uid=swg2C1123456`